# How to find overall CPU usage in a multi-tenant environment?

Tags: cpu-usage, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I have a single server/multiple workers architecture to run distributed queries. Once a query finishes, it reports back to the server the total time taken for completion and I maintain a running counter of the total CPU time (`totalCpuTime`) for completion of ALL the queries. With this count I want to expose the overall CPU Usage of the cluster on the server.

I was thinking of polling for the `totalCpuTime` every 3 minutes (sampling rate). Lets say I have two data-points `d1` and `d2` which are `sampling_rate = 1800s` apart. I did `cpuUsage = (d2 - d1)/total_number_of_workers * sampling_rate` but this is giving me a number greater than 100 and I don't know how to make sense of it.

Any ideas or other approaches?

Comment: what platform? EC2, XEN>

Comment: The workers are all EC2 instances.